# How to run multiple tests with pytest with a qualifier test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a directory of pytest test files, and there is a qualifier test that needs to be tested and if it fails then stop executing any further tests but if it passed then execute all tests whether any passes or fails.
I have a directory with following structure :

```
tests/
test_qualifier.py
test_one.py
test_two.py
...
```

Now when I run the tests using `pytest test/ -x` it runs all the tests given that it stops at the first failure.
I want `pytest` to run `test_qualifier.py` and if it fails then stop further execution but if it passes then do not stop whether or not any test fails.

Comment: This isn't a question. Please extend it and consider including code snippets showing how you're running it.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a feature which makes much sense in general so I don't see pytest supporting it out of the box.

However you can probably roll it out yourself: in `test_qualifier`, create an `autouse` fixture which [checks the result of the test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) and calls something like `pytest.exit` if one of the tests failed. Maybe check how `--exitfirst` works if you want proper reporting, I don't know if a straight call to `pytest.exit` will generate the normal failure report so that might be less than great.

Alternatively to `pytest.exit` you could set an internal flag which would get use by [a test running hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#test-running-hooks) to automatically skip all later tests.

You may also want to write a `conftest` plugin hooked into [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) to ensure your qualification tests always run first and you're not subjected to the vagaries of direntry iteration or alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest-depends plugin. Mark other tests as a dependant on test_qualifier.

From the [plugin page](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-depends/):

> This pytest plugin allows you to declare dependencies between pytest tests, where dependent tests will not run if the tests they depend on did not succeed.
>
> Of course, tests should be self contained whenever possible, but that doesn't mean this doesn't have good uses.
>
> This can be useful for when the failing of a test means that another test cannot possibly succeed either, especially with slower tests. This isn't a dependency in the sense of test A sets up stuff for test B, but more in the sense of if test A failed there's no reason to bother with test B either.

Code sample:

```
BUILD_PATH = 'build'

def test_build_exists():
    assert os.path.exists(BUILD_PATH)

@pytest.depends(on=['test_build_exists'])
def test_build_version():
    result = subprocess.run([BUILD_PATH, '--version', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    assert result.returncode == 0
    assert '1.2.3' in result.stdout
```

You can achieve the same by writing your own pytest plugin using pytest hooks.

Comment: It works, Thanks. But i encountered another problem, I need to run the test suite N times and for this i used command line option,"--count N" so whenever i gave the count more than 1 the dependent tests were skipped every time. Not sure what is causing the tests to skip :(

Comment: That is a separate issue. A working code sample would be needed to debug that issue. And, you must be using pytest-repeat plugin to repeat a test. One needs to look into the internals of that plugin too to get an idea of the problem.